# What does the red icon and Notification in the panel mean please? And how can I remove it?

Tags: dependencies

This is the error message. How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: It sort of says what to do. In the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` the 60th entry is wrong. Edit your question and paste the contents of this file into it, so we can tell what the error is.

Comment: this is the typical brocken package message under ubuntu 16 or 17 I'm not sure but it's easily fixable most of the time it involves removing a faulty PPA from your sources, running `sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt update` at the update you should know already if packages have been fixed or not, if yes ther'll be no error message. then you can run `sudo apt full-upgrade`